# Using a .Net Standard 2.0 library in a UWP app has to be Windows Runtime compatible?

Tags: .net, uwp, windows-runtime, .net-standard-2.0

I made a .net standard 2.0 library just to experiment with things. I referenced it in a UWP app targeting fall creators update. So good so far, except it does not compile, giving me errors about the interfaces not implementing windows runtime like

> 'Type 'MyInterface1' implements interface 'MyInterface2', which is not a Windows Runtime interface.  All interfaces that are implemented by exported types must be Windows Runtime interfaces.'

MyInterface2 is just an empty public interface:

> public interface MyInterface2
>       {
>       }

I've only find [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/creating-windows-runtime-components-in-csharp-and-visual-basic)
but is does not seem like I break any rules.
I'm kind of lost. Any idea why is that?  Also, why does my interface have to be a Windows Runtime interface?
I thought the point of .net standard is to not have to deal with these kind of incompatibilities.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue on my side, I created an interface in the library and reference the library to UWP app that target 16299, the app can run without errors. Could  you please provide the detail reproduce steps or a [mcve]?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT Hey, I was able to overcome the issue. When I tried with an IoT Core background application the problem above occurred. When I tried with a simple blank uwp app, it works; no errors. In the end I was right that .net standard solves these problems, although I did not investigate why the background app did not work. I guess the template I installed externally did not get updated to use .net standard 2.0?

Comment: Did you install [this template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MicrosoftIoT.WindowsIoTCoreProjectTemplatesforVS15)? And invoke the .Net-standart 2.0  library from a Background Application(Iot) project?

Comment: Yes that was it.